# Google App Engine : Calling Multiple Back end Inside a task queue in a sequence

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a 6 back ends servlet which i want to schedule it in a sequence .

I want to schedule them in a sequence as order specified in BackendQueueServlet .

Here s my task queue code :

```
public class BackendQueueServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String key = "aaaaaa";

        // Add the task to the default queue.
        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("BackendQueue");


        queue.add(withUrl("/twitterservlet").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("twitterservlet")));


        queue.add(withUrl("/facebookservlet").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("facebookservlet")));

        queue.add(withUrl("/loadingservlet").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("loadingservlet")));

        queue.add(withUrl("/fbcomments").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("fbcomments")));

        queue.add(withUrl("/fbcomments").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("fbcomments")));

        queue.add(withUrl("/fbcomments").method(Method.GET).param("key", key).header(
                "Host",
                BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("fbcomments")));        

    }
}
```

And here's my backend.xml

```
<backends>


      <backend name="twitterservlet">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>

     <backend name="facebookservlet">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>

    <backend name="loadingservlet">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>


     <backend name="fbcomments">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>


       <backend name="topinfluencer">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>

</backends>
```

Comment: Can you provide more background on what you want to achieve? AppEngine Task Queues are inherently asynchronous (AppEngine does not even guarantee that tasks will be executed at the same order as they were enqueued, even if it does most of the time). If you really want a synchronous task management system, you need to build it by yourself using task queue and datastore. Also using one backend per taskqueue may be overkill...